# get value of changed JTextField on Java Swing

Tags: java

Hey guyz i'm working on a GPA calculator for my java assignment, and the gui i have created is 100% based on Events i.e.  no buttons for the user to submit his data. my question is how do i know if a textfield value has changed and if it did how do i get the original value befor the change.
another question how can i store each component in an arrayList do the user can create as many rows as they like Thanks
this is the snapshot of mu GUI[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lrtv.png)
BTW feel free any other suggestion

Comment: Show what you have completed, so I can help on this. The problem is pretty simple to solve, if you show your part of work.

Comment: are you serious?? because my dead line is 3 days latter, that would awesome, i'm pretty much done i just have to put everything together and add some constraints and properties to the fields, like this one. so how can i show you everything

Comment: okay how can i let the user  continue from where they left so they can add new record and edit the older one. the model of the app is it updates the results the minute a user makes change on any record. kind of domino effect. how should i keep track of number of records

Answer (score 0):

You can use keylistener

```
    JTextField usernameTextField= newJTextField(); 
usernameTextField.addKeyListener(new () { public void keyReleased(Key KeyAdapter Event e) { JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getSource(); String text = textField.getText(); textField.setText(text.toUpperCase()); } public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { } public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { } });
```

Comment: This code is the same as using Document listener, it does something when ever the text field is updated. what i want is get the value of the text field before it was edited

Comment: I have updated code you can use keypressed method to get the event before typing